# jQuery addClass() function in if statement

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having problems with jQuery and I could not find anything that could help me in any way.

So what I'm trying to do is to change the colour of the "cursor" class to green when the number of potatoes is more than the cost of the cursor. So what I want to happen is that the text "Buy Cursor" is green if potatoes is more than cursorCost.

Here is the HTML & jQuery code:

```
    <html>

<head>
    <title>Potato Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="left">
        <img id="potato-img" onClick="potatoClick(clickPower)" src="stockvault-potatoes107220.jpg" width="300" height="300">
        <br>
        <div id="mainDisplay">
            <span id="potatoes">0</span> 
            <br>potatoes
            <br>
            <br>Producing <span id="pps">0</span> potatoes per second
            <br>
            <button onClick="save()">&nbsp; Save &nbsp;</button>
            <br>
            <button onClick="reset()">&nbsp; Reset &nbsp;</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="middle-buy">
        <br>
        <div id="buildings" class="cursor" onClick="buyCursor()">&nbsp; Buy Cursor &nbsp;</div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="buildings" class="farmer" onClick="buyFarmer()">&nbsp; Buy Farmer &nbsp;</div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="buildings" class="breeder" onClick="buyBreeder()">&nbsp; Buy Breeder &nbsp;</div>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div id="middle-cost">
        <div style="font-size: 18px">Next building costs:</div>
        <div id="cost"><span id="cursorCost">10</span> potatoes</div>
        <br>
        <div id="cost"><span id="farmerCost">100</span> potatoes</div>
        <br>
        <div id="cost"><span id="breederCost">500</span> potatoes</div>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div id="middle-info">
        <br>
        <div id="quantity"><span id="cursors">0</span> cursors clicking away at <span id="cursorPps">0</span> potatoes per second</div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="quantity"><span id="farmers">0</span> farmers farming at <span id="farmerPps">0</span> potatoes per second</div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="quantity"><span id="breeders">0</span> breeders breeding at <span id="breederPps">0</span> potatoes per second</div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>


    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            window.setInterval(function () {

                if (potatoes >= cursorCost) {

                    $(".cursor").addClass("buyable");

                };

            }, 1000);

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.cursor.buyable {

 color: green;

}
```

Now the problem is that although I am using the correct selector, the text under

```
class="cursor"
```

does not turn green when

```
potatoes > cursorCost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your selector:

```
$("cursor")
```

If you want the element with the `cursor` `id` change it to:

```
$("#cursor")
```

If you need element with the `cursor` `class` change it to:

```
$(".cursor")
```

Comment: Oh. If its for the element with the cursor class then how do you update the text color?

Like how document.getElementById works for ids,
is there something else for classes?

Comment: $('.cursor') is the selector in jQuery for elements with the cursor class. For more info refer to: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear what I meant was what is the class version of document.getElementById? Is it document.getElementByClass?